# Elixir - filter list of items with overlapping dates with a given date range

Tags: elixir

I need to refactor a function that filters a list of projects by a given date range:

```
defp filter_by_date_range(projects, %{start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date} = _report) do
  projects
  |> Enum.filter(&Date.compare(&1.start_date, start_date) in [:gt, :eq])
  |> Enum.filter(&Date.compare(&1.end_date, end_date) in [:lt, :eq])
end
```

Right now, what it does is it returns the projects whose start dates and end dates fall in between the report's `start_date` and `end_date`. I want to modify it so that it will return projects as long there is an overlap of the dates. Example:

- project's start date falls between report's `start_date` and `end_date` but project's end date is later than report's `end_date`, accept
- project's end date falls between report's `start_date` and `end_date` but project's start date is earlier than report's `start_date`, accept
- project's start and end dates fall between report's `start_date` and `end_date`, accept (the current implementation)
- report's `start_date` and `end_date` fall between project's start date and end date, accept
- project's start and end dates are both earlier than report's `start_date`, reject
- project's start and end dates are both later than report's `end_date`, reject

I came up with this nifty solution, but is there anything I can do to improve it?

```
defp filter_by_date_range(projects, %{start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date}) do
  Enum.filter(projects, &do_dates_overlap?(&1, start_date, end_date))
end

defp do_dates_overlap?(project, start_date, end_date) do
  cond do
    Date.compare(project.end_date, start_date) == :lt -> false
    Date.compare(project.start_date, end_date) == :gt -> false
    true -> true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can safely make the assumption you'll never have a single-day report on the same day as a single-day project, you could just check that your comparisons are not equal:

```rb
defp do_dates_overlap?(project, start_date, end_date) do
  Date.compare(project.end_date, start_date) != Date.compare(project.start_date, end_date)
end
```

If you can't make that assumption, you can just `and` them together:

```rb
defp do_dates_overlap?(project, start_date, end_date) do
  Date.compare(project.end_date, start_date) != :lt and Date.compare(project.start_date, end_date) != :gt
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply join the filters with boolean `OR`:

```rb
defp filter_by_date_range(projects, %{start_date: sd, end_date: ed}) do
  Enum.filter(projects, &
    Date.compare(&1.start_date, sd) in [:gt, :eq] or
    Date.compare(&1.end_date, ed) in [:lt, :eq] or
    (
      Date.compare(&1.start_date, sd) == :lt and
      Date.compare(&1.end_date, ed) == :gt
    )
  )
end
```

---

or, less explicit:

```rb
defp filter_by_date_range(projects, %{start_date: sd, end_date: ed}) do
  Enum.filter(projects, & not(
    Date.compare(&1.end_date, sd) == :lt or
    Date.compare(&1.start_date, ed) == :gt
  )
end
```

Comment: That doesn't cover the 4th case though

Comment: I have not obviously read all the required conditions, and the headline of the answer _is_ actually already an answer. OK, I updated it to cover case #4.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to compare if two periods overlap (or intersect) is to check if the following condition is true:

```
p1_start <= p2_end && p2_start <= p1_end
```

For your case, there would be overlap (or intersection) if:

```
defp filter_by_date_range(projects, %{start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date} = _report) do
  Enum.filter(projects, &(Date.compare(&1.start_date, end_date) != :gt and Date.compare(start_date, &1.end_date) != :gt))
end
```

It even works just as good for periods of one day.

Comment: There may be some assumptions or a special case you're exploiting that I fail to understand, but normally you cannot safely use the comparison operators with `%DateTime{}` or `%NaiveDateTime{}`. Your example might work with an integer (i.e. after calling `DateTime.to_unix/1`

From the DateTime module docs:
`Remember, comparisons in Elixir using ==/2, >/2, </2 and friends are structural and based on the DateTime struct fields. For proper comparison between datetimes, use the compare/2 function.`

Comment: @JasonTrue My bad, you are totally right. I've adjusted my answer. Thanks.

Comment: no problem, I've just fixed this bug in our own codebases enough times that I notice it instantly. (And who knows, sometimes there's an actual use case for structural equality comparison with DateTime that I've missed :P)